# how do i include files on my LS-XL413 intranet drive in a php document?

Tags: php

My computer is being filled up with external files that i access via php include/require statements, so I decided to put them on an intranet drive to preserve space. However, well trying to do so I encountered a problem. How do I write a link to a file on an intranet drive?

Here is my include code I have tried: (UPDATE: I tried the `echo file_get_contents("foo")` method and it still produces an error. Any other ideas?) (UPDATE[1]: How do I map drive letters to a network drive?)

```
<header>
<div class="branding"> <img src="images/ralogo_monogram.png" alt="Logo">
  <p>Roux Academy<br>
    Art • Media • Design</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <h1>Roux Academy 2016 Art Conference</h1>
  <p>Join over 500 hundred of the most creative and brilliant minds of art colleges all around the world for five days of lectures by world-renowned art scholars and artists, and seven days and nights of gallery exhibits featuring the best in contemporary art, including painting, sculpture, and more, in the beautiful halls of Hotel Contempo in the heart of Seattle.</p>
</div>
<?php include "192.168.1.67/share/server_includes/navbar.html"; ?>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on Windows, map this intranet drive to a drive letter on your computer. Then `include` or `require` the files in your php code like you've always done.

If on Linux/Unix/Mac OS, mount the drive into a folder on your computer. Then `include` or `require` the files in your php code like you've always done.

Compared to file_get_contents(), this solution lets ypou preserve the distinction between `include` and `require`.

I could not find details on your LS-XL413 drive just from the model name. Give us a link and let us know what OS you are using, so that we can give you more detailed instructions on mapping/mounting the drive.

Comment: Windows, and how do I assign a drive letter? (specifics: Windows 10)

Comment: Can you add a link to the product page of the drive you are using? I can't find the drive, so I don't know whether it shares the data via NFS/CIFS/something else. I'll check back tomorrow.